# chosen not working on cloned elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am cloning a div that contains a field using the chosen library. If I clone a bunch of them and **don't** put my cursor in the chosen field to initialize the dropdown, then all of the chosen fields work.

However, if I put my cursor in the chosen field (the dropdown is then initialized) and *then* clone the div, the subsequent chosen fields will not initialize the dropdown. The divs that the chosen library adds are being added, but the actual input/select functionality doesn't work.

```
$(".addCondition").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    conditions++;
    if ($(this).hasClass("addCampaignBehavior")) {
      $(".campaignsOriginal").clone(true).appendTo(".conditionsHere").removeClass("campaignsOriginal").show();
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("addAutomationBehavior")) {
      $(".automationsOriginal").clone(true).appendTo(".conditionsHere").removeClass("automationsOriginal").show(); 
    }
  });
  $(".conditionField").change(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("nextChosen")) {
      $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("lastCondition")) {
      $(this).next(".finalConditions").show();
    }
    $(this).next(".conditionItem").css('display','inline-block');
  });
```

Comment: Cloned elements may be identical to their original, but that doesn't necessarily mean meta data a plugin stores about a particular element will be magically cloned as well.  You will probably have to initialize the new cloned elements when you create them for them to work.

Comment: @Taplar I tried adding $(".chosen-select").chosen(); after cloning, but that doesn't work either

Comment: You wouldn't want to re-initialize every element on the page.  Just the one you cloned.  So you'd store it in a var, initialize just that one, and then append it.  If that doesn't work, and you are still doing clone(true), you might try doing it without the true.  Could possibly be dorking something up, *shrug*

Comment: @Taplar the problem is I need the (true) because I have other logic within the div. What I don't understand is that all of the .chosen() functionality is working _except_ showing the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up fixing it:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("nextChosen")) {
      $(this).siblings().children(".chosen-select").chosen();
    }
```

did the trick

Comment: Where did you put that code though? Is it possible to post a *full* solution? Thanks.